# "Rust" way of returning mutable reference to incoming or newly created struct from function

Tags: rust

This is simple in other languages I know, but I'm confused how to solve it the Rust / Right way.

I have a complex struct, which isn't Copy/Clone able. I want to write a function, which has an optional reference parameter of that struct, if the optional parameter is None it should create it. The parameter or newly created struct variable must be mutable.
After the function ends it should return either the parameter or the newly created variable.
I get why the code irritates the borrow-checker, since the struct lifetime may differ, depending on the input.
I assume I can't just add lifetime specifiers and must use ARC (Automatic Reference Counter)?

But how, I feel lost?

Here is the abstract code:

```rust
struct Complex {
    value: i32,
}

impl Complex {
    fn new() -> Complex {
        Complex { value: 3 }
    }

    fn setup(&mut self) {
        self.value = 2;
    }

    fn change(&mut self) {
        self.value += 5;
    }
}

fn do_it(complex_opt: Option<&mut Complex>) -> Box<&mut Complex> {
    let mut complex: &mut Complex = match complex_opt {
        Some(complex2) => complex2,
        None => {
            let mut complex2 = Complex::new();
            complex2.setup();
            &mut complex2
        }
    };
    // Variable must be mutable because of multiple mutable function calls.
    complex.change();

    Box::new(complex)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=014e657f8c0ddef530cd96440c0dfd5c)

Comment: That code isn't valid in any language I know as it would create a dangling reference/pointer which is UB in other languages, too. Where do you want to store the new `Complex`?

Comment: The borrow checker isn't bothered by any difference in lifetimes btw, it's complaining because your code creates a dangling reference.

Comment: "ARC (Automatic Reference Counter)" Arc only means "automatic reference counting" in swift, in rust it means "atomic reference counting", aka thread-safe reference counting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, at least not with references. (Edit: it is *technically* possible with `Box::leak`, but you really don't want to go down that path)

Note that this is not something specific to Rust, it isn't possible in **any** programming language to return a reference to a local variable.

Specifically this part is impossible:

```rust
{
    let mut complex2 = Complex::new();
    complex2.setup();
    &mut complex2
}
```

This is what the compiler complains about, **not** the lifetime difference between the input and the output. The compiler is capable of connecting the input and output lifetimes automatically if you don't annotate them manually.

The paradigm you are talking about is probably either `C` or `Python`. Those do not work with references, so it is possible.

There are in general three ways to refer to a value:

- via pointer (C)
- via reference counter / garbage collector (Python)
- via reference (your example)

And of course, ownership.

This pattern is **only** possible with owned values, pointers or reference counters. With normal references, this will **always** be undefined behavior.

Consider the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct {
    int x;
};

MyStruct& foo() {
    MyStruct s{x: 42};
    return s;
}
```

```
<source>: In function 'MyStruct& foo()':
<source>:8:14: warning: reference to local variable 's' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     MyStruct s{x: 42};
              ^
```

The difference between C++ and Rust is that C++ **allows** undefined behavior, and hence only prints a warning. When running this code, though, anything can happen. It is undefined behavior.

Those three examples, however, are completely legal:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct MyStruct {
    int x;

    MyStruct(int x){
        this->x = x;
    }
};


MyStruct foo_1() {
    MyStruct s = {42};
    return s;
}

MyStruct* foo_2() {
    MyStruct* s = new MyStruct(42);
    return s;
}

std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> foo_3() {
    std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> s = std::make_shared<MyStruct>(42);
    return s;
}
```

The reason `foo_1` works is because the value gets moved out of the function. `foo_2` and `foo_3` work because in the both cases, the object is stored on the **heap**, not on the current stackframe.

There are of course equivalents to all those data types in Rust:

- `std::unique_ptr` -> `Box`
- `std::shared_ptr`, or how all variables work in Python -> `Rc`, or `Rc<RefCell>`, or `Arc<Mutex>`, depending on the situation
- pointers -> Rust's `unsafe` raw pointers

Which one to choose of course depends on your situation. I would generally avoid `unsafe` unless absolutely necessary, so here is an example with `Box`:

```rust
struct Complex {
    value: i32,
}

impl Complex {
    fn new() -> Complex {
        Complex { value: 3 }
    }

    fn setup(&mut self) {
        self.value = 2;
    }

    fn change(&mut self) {
        self.value += 5;
    }
}

fn do_it(complex_opt: Option<Box<Complex>>) -> Box<Complex> {
    let mut complex = complex_opt.unwrap_or_else(|| {
        let mut complex2 = Box::new(Complex::new());
        complex2.setup();
        complex2
    });

    complex.change();

    complex
}
```

Although `Box` is really not necessary here, you can simply use ownership instead:

```rust
fn do_it(complex_opt: Option<Complex>) -> Complex {
    let mut complex = complex_opt.unwrap_or_else(|| {
        let mut complex2 = Complex::new();
        complex2.setup();
        complex2
    });

    complex.change();

    complex
}
```

Although it is of course valid to use `Box<Complex>`, especially if the type is large enough that one should avoid moving it repeatedly.

---

As you specifically also asked about `Arc`, here are two more code examples.

One with `Rc<RefCell>`, for the single threaded case:

```rust
fn do_it(complex_opt: Option<Rc<RefCell<Complex>>>) -> Rc<RefCell<Complex>> {
    let mut complex = complex_opt.unwrap_or_else(|| {
        let mut complex2 = Complex::new();
        complex2.setup();
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(complex2))
    });

    complex.borrow_mut().change();

    complex
}
```

And another one with `Arc<Mutex>`, for the multi-threaded case:

```rust
fn do_it(complex_opt: Option<Arc<Mutex<Complex>>>) -> Arc<Mutex<Complex>> {
    let mut complex = complex_opt.unwrap_or_else(|| {
        let mut complex2 = Complex::new();
        complex2.setup();
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(complex2))
    });

    complex.lock().unwrap().change();

    complex
}
```

Note that in all cases, this is only possible if the **input** variable is also already an `Rc`/`Arc`. It isn't possible to convert a reference to a `Box`/`Rc`/`Arc`. They all require ownership to be created, as they physically move the value to the heap.

EDIT: Also regard @cafce25's answer, he shows a way to solve this with a reference as an input, by using an `enum`. This is more complex, but of course also works.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great and good explained answer. I ended using `Rc<RefCell<>>`, because I reuse the `Complex` struct very often in one function (it's actually a buffer). And otherwise I get constant complains about conflicts with moved variables and borrowing - and I can't clone / copy the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

You could return an `enum` that can hold either something owned or a reference:

```rust
enum OobMut<'a, T> {
    Owned(T),
    Borrowed(&'a mut T),
}

impl<T> std::ops::Deref for OobMut<'_, T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        use OobMut::*;
        match self {
            Owned(t) => t,
            Borrowed(t) => t,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> std::ops::DerefMut for OobMut<'_, T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        use OobMut::*;
        match self {
            Owned(t) => t,
            Borrowed(t) => t,
        }
    }
}

fn do_it(complex_opt: Option<&mut Complex>) -> OobMut<Complex> {
    let mut complex = match complex_opt {
        Some(complex2) => OobMut::Borrowed(complex2),
        None => {
            let mut complex2 = Complex::new();
            complex2.setup();
            OobMut::Owned(complex2)
        }
    };
    // Variable must be mutable because of multiple mutable function calls.
    complex.change();

    complex
}
```

Implementing `Deref` and `DerefMut` isn't strictly necessary but makes working with an `OobMut<T>` almost the same as if you had a `&mut T`.

That type is almost available as [`mucow::MuCow`](https://docs.rs/mucow/latest/mucow/) with the additional constraint that `T` has to implement `ToOwned`.

Comment: That's also an alternative :) With the drawback, though, that resulting type will be lifetime-bound to the input. But if that's OK, that's probably the closest to OP's original code :)